# Data Driven Subscription Special Characters needed in File Name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a data driven subscription with the file name as one of the columns in the object that SSRS uses to fulfill the subscription.

The file name is the subject of the report. I have tested this a few ways and the error is happening with the file name, not when I pass the item as a parameter.

For example, the report as a single Parameter, Item.

The report is written to a file share:

- Path: `\\directory\store`
- Parameter: `Item=Blue&White`
- File Name: `Blue&White.pdf`

I have tried substituting the "&" with other characters, and of course it works, but it is really important for the file to be named Blue&White.pdf

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is interpreting the '&' as an argument separator as [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

You may want to consider different encoding of the [Unicode Character 'AMPERSAND' (U+0026)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0026/index.htm). However since '&' is used as an escape character you options may be limited.

```
&amp;
%26
\u0026
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more detailed. I tried a number of the replace options with no success. I actually got the customer to buy off on using a hyphen to replace the special characters. Out of thousands of "items" very few are impacted. Not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a data driven subscription and used the SQL command to set the filename. The REPLACE function was used to change '&' to 'and'.